# How can I fetch data from database using this prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
//this is my connection function. It is connecting databse successfully when I check.
$conn = connection($config['servername'],$config['username'],$config['password']);
```

after this I Used following code to fetch data from Database

```
$id = 2;
if($conn) {

    try {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM customer_tbl WHERE cus_id = :id');
        $stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

        $results = $stmt->execute();

    }catch (PDOException $e){

        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

this code showing following error message on the browser

> Error: SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: This driver doesn't support setting attributes

what's wrong with my code?. Why I could not fetch data's from database?

if I want to fetch this specified data from databese using prepare statement 
how to code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error mode is not an attribute of the statement but of the connection.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following

```
$stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

after the connection string with `$conn` Object

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

To fetch data use

```
$stmt->execute();    
$rows= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($rows); // to print an array
```

it will return data in associative array format.
PDO provides various fetch options [look here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: ok now error message has been removed after this how can fetch data to the browser

Comment: this is what I have used before but I got Fatal Error that `Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in`